# How to generalize Hopf Umlaufsatz to closed curves with self-intersecting points?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

The Hopf Umlaufsatz states that the angle of the tangent along a simple smooth closed plane curve turns by +360 or -360 degrees. See curve (1) in the following picture. The Hopf Umlaufsatz can be proved by the deformation trick. See this [page](https://mathematik.com/Hopf/index.html).
For the sketch of proof, see pages 27-28 of Professor Theodore Shifrin's [book](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

A plane curve is a map $c:[0, L]\to \mathbb{R}^2$. If $c(0)=c(L)$, then the curve is closed.  The curve is simple if for every $0<s_1<s_2<L$ we have $c(s_1)\neq c(s_2)$. If there are $s_1$ and $s_2$ satisfying $0<s_1<s_2<L$ and $c(s_1)=c(s_2)$, then $s_1$ and $s_2$ are called the self-intersecting points. See the following picture.

[image: The image of two curves]

For a curve with self-intersecting points, curve (2) in the above picture, the Hopf Umlaufsatz is not applicable. Which line of the proof in the [book](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) would not hold?

Intuitively, the angle of the tangent along curve (2) turns by +720 or -720 degrees.
Can we use the deformation trick to prove this statement?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please make your post self-contained.

Comment: For starters, define “self-intersecting points” and say what result you would try to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to answer your question: The chordal map $\mathbf h$ is not defined when $s=s_1$ and $t=s_2$.

If you want to analyze this further, I suggest you look at (and prove!) Exercise 13, which gives a generalization of the Hopf Umlaufsatz to the case of a piecewise smooth curve; you can write your non-simple curve as the union of two curves, each with a corner point.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to prove Exercise 13.